# How to read classpath resources in Quarkus native image?

Tags: quarkus

I already got add the resource to the classpath using

```
<additionalBuildArg>-H:IncludeResources=.*/kubernetes_auth.crt$</additionalBuildArg>
<additionalBuildArg>-H:Log=registerResource:verbose</additionalBuildArg>
```

When I build the image I can see in the log that if I add it

```
ResourcesFeature: registerResource: classes/kubernetes_auth.crt
```

But when I try to read the resource with the following code that works in Java, it returns null

```
InputStream is = KubernetesResource.class.getResourceAsStream("/kubernetes_auth.crt");
```

I have tried with these variants but same returns null

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/kubernetes_auth.crt");
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/kubernetes_auth.crt");
getClass().getResourceAsStream("classes/kubernetes_auth.crt");
```

Versions of quuarkus 0.13.3 and 0.14.0 and Graal rc14, rc15, rc16

Comment: Do you have a reproducer project we could use to test?

Comment: Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("myFile.txt") works fine for me. Using Quarkus 0.27.0

Answer (score 3):

As you discovered, you need to specify the resource to be loaded.

As of Quarkus 1.8.0 (and for some time before), you can list resources that should be available for the native image to load using a property:

```
quarkus.native.resources.includes=kubernetes_auth.crt
```

The property supports a comma-separated list of files. The syntax for this list is described in the configuration reference for building native images: https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image#configuration-reference